# How to display comments of a particular post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to display comments of a selected post in wordpress. How can I display comments of a particular post by id?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us what you're currently doing.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38753/how-to-get-comments-by-post-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find out your post_id of the post where you want to fetch the comments from.

```
<?php 
  // Get all comments of post_id 5
  $args = array('post_id' => 5);
  $comments = get_comments( $args ); 

  // Loop through your comments
  foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo($comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content);
  endforeach;
?>
```